# Impedance waveform

Tags: impedance

How to get a good picture of fft of Impedance with voltage and current signals ? ( How to deal with zero crossings of current as impedance is taken as (V/I) ?

Answer (score 2):

The Fourier Transform (including FFT) transforms a quantity to its inverse. In most applications that will be a time domain into a frequency domain (frequency is 1/time).

Typically you'll sample your quantity as a function of time, like a voltage waveform. The FFT will show you a spectrum of the frequencies with their phase which constitute that waveform.

An FFT of impedance is not useful, as impedance is usually constant, and the FFT will only show a zero frequency.

You mention zero-crossing, but those are in the time domain, and it will probably be easier to stay there. You can easily measure the phase difference between voltage and current when you measure the time between their zero-crossings:

Phase \$ \theta = \dfrac{\Delta t}{T} 360° \$

where \$T\$ is the signal's period. That phase also indicates the ratio between the impedance's resistance \$R\$ and reactance \$X\$:

\$ \dfrac{X}{R} = arctan(\theta) \$

The ratio between voltage and current amplitude give you the impedance

\$ Z = \sqrt{R^2 + X^2} \$

With those two equations you should be able to find \$R\$ and \$X\$. All in the time domain, no need for FFTs.

Comment: i have some what similar problem kindly look at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11196/implementation-of-the-algorith-on-arduino